# How to write from normal javascript code to Closure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am creating a web app where I want the user to increase/decrease the text size. All I need to do is change this code to use closure.

```
var $button = $("p");  
$button.each( function(){
var $this = $(this);
$this.css("font-size");
});

$("#larger").click(function(){
fontSize (1);
})

$("#smaller").click(function(){
 fontSize (-1);
})

function fontSize(right){
$button.each( function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css( "font-size" , parseInt($this.css("font-size")) + right);
});
}
```

> Here is my closure part. Can someone tell me if this is correct?

```
 var $button = $("p");
 $button.each(function() {
 $(this).css("font-size");
});
$("#larger").click(function() {
 fontSize(1);
 });
  $("#smaller").click(function() {
  fontSize(-1);
  });
  function fontSize(b) {
  $button.each(function() {
  var a = $(this);
   a.css("font-size", parseInt(a.css("font-size")) + b);
  });
  }
```

Comment: perhaps someone who knows closureJS ... but they may not see this question because you haven't tagged it as such ... don't count on it though, because you should show at least some attempt to solve your problem yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:**
Mozilla has great tutorials [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

```js
function makeSizer(size) {
  return function() {
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
  };
}

var size12 = makeSizer(12);
var size14 = makeSizer(14);
var size16 = makeSizer(16);

document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = size12;
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = size14;
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = size16;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="size-12">12</a>
<a href="#" id="size-14">14</a>
<a href="#" id="size-16">16</a>
```

The question is posed a bit vaguely, however, if the question was about Javascript closures then I suggest [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). It is the official guide from Mozilla regarding closures and it has an example exactly which provides your answer.